# Use @version with spring is not working if it is remove in the json

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

We have a DTO

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "agenda")
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class Agenda implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -4588716014801416553L;

  @Id
  private String id;

  @Version
  private Long version = 1L;

  @Column(name = "nombre")
  private String name;

  @JsonIgnore
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "agenda", targetEntity = Timetable.class)
  private Set<Timetable> timetables;

}
```

in this dto we have added an @version of javax.persistence, and is working well if we sent to the controller a json with the field version, in other case fail when it try to save into database.

for example if we send:

```
"agenda": {
  "name": "Agenda 1",
   "id": "agenda1",
   "version": 1
},
```

is working without any problem, but if we remove version it throwing an exception, so my question is, is version field always mandatory?,

And the error is : could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [horario_id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that we were using a wrong  import, we must use

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Version;
```

instead of

```
import javax.persistence.Version;
```